# Permission error from Supervisor when full PHP path not specified

Tags: linux, php, supervisord, debian-stretch, php-cli

I've compiled PHP from source on Debian Stretch in a docker container.

I have added this entry to my Supervisor config:

```
command=/bin/sh -c 'QUEUE=orders/create APP_INCLUDE=/var/www/html/jobs/OrdersCreate.php php /var/www/html/includes/vendor/resque/php-resque/resque.php >> /var/www/log/OrdersCreate.log 2>&1'
autostart=true
autorestart=true
priority=11
stdout_events_enabled=true
stderr_events_enabled=true
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

It logs the error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: php: Permission denied.
```

If I add the full path to PHP `/usr/bin/php/bin/php`, it works fine.

Why is this and how can I make it work without specifying the full path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit the `$PATH` environment variable to include the location which the `php` binary exists in.

In your Dockerfile:

```
ENV PATH "$PATH:/usr/bin/php/bin"
```

Comment: I had previously done that with `export PATH=/usr/bin/php/bin:$PATH` that I found from another post. Was that incorrect?

Comment: Both methods should work.  Adding what I posted to the Dockerfile means this modification is part of the image.  That could also be the case if you have a shell script (containing the `export` line) which runs while the container is built (Via a `RUN` command in the Dockerfile).  I would avoid applying this at container runtime though (For example in an `ENTRYPOINT` script, as it should really be part of the image in my opinion.

Comment: I tested it before by adding it after the container was built. I'll rebuild it adding this line instead.